# How to stream music from Spotify in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi guys I need help on how to go about streaming music from Spotify from my flutter app. So I have a music player on the app and just need to stream music from Spotify.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://pub.dev/packages/spotify_sdk) is what you are looking for I think.

If this is not what you need, please let me know and I will provide more support, happy coding!